# Querying data in Delta lake using Rust delta-rs

Tags: rust, parquet

How to query data that is in a DeltaLake table using Rust with Delta-rs. In my case, the data is in multiple parquet files.
Thank you

Could you please give me a small code that is working from your side?

Answer (score 1):

You will need either Polars or Datafusion to do so.
Here is a naive approach in rust:

```rust
use deltalake::delta::open_table;
use polars::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let lf = read_delta_table("delta_test_5m").await;
    println!("{:?}", lf.select([count()]).collect());

    
}

async fn read_delta_table(path: &str) -> LazyFrame {
    let dt = open_table(path).await.unwrap();
    let files = dt.get_files();
    let mut df_collection: Vec<DataFrame> = vec![];
    for file_path in files.into_iter() {
        let full_path = format!("{}/{}", path, file_path.as_ref());
        let mut file = std::fs::File::open(full_path).unwrap();
        let df = ParquetReader::new(&mut file).finish().unwrap();
        df_collection.push(df);
    }

    let empty_head = df_collection[0].clone().lazy().limit(0);
    df_collection.into_iter().fold(empty_head, |acc, df| concat([acc, df.lazy()], false, false).unwrap())
}
```

This code first get the list of the parquet files to take into account for the most recent version of the delta table.
Then one Dataframe is created for each file.
Finally, these Dataframe are concatenated to get a final Dataframe.

Note that Polars offers this feature out of the box in Python:

```py
import polars as pl

print(pl.read_delta("path_to_delta"))
```

I did not find how to read Delta directly through Polars in Rust but it should be added soon I guess.